# How to make UILabel as narrow as possible with multiple lines?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, uilabel

I have a UILabel that's got 2 lines of text.  (I want to force 2 lines).  I set some constraints on it so that it's got certain insets on the left and right.  The text always comes out where the top line is a lot longer than the bottom.  I want both lines' width to be as close to the other as possible.  How can I do this?  I have localization so I can't just move the insets in.

Comment: You will have to calculate the needed width yourself at runtime. There is nothing built in to automatically size a `UILabel to get the results you want.

Comment: Did you ever manage this?